# How to pass argument to a par file

Tags: oracle, import

For oracle db imports I have a par file which needs to be updated for each run.  Is there a way to pass an argument to this file?

The .par file looks like this:

```
full=y
logfile=impdp-mylog.log
dumpfile=myDb.dmp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command line arguments will override the parameter file arguments.

```
impdp "'/ as sysdba'" parfile=myparfile.par logfile=impdp.myDB.dmp.log directory=importdir
```